# How to hide output (not the window) in a console application?

Tags: c#, command-line, console, console-application, command-line-arguments

Well, let me make it clear again. I have a console application with many classes, in each class there is at least one Console.WriteLine("text") line. I defined some arguments that when running the application, it output exactly what I wrote in classes. There, I want to define an argument that when I run the app with this argument, there will be no output on the console screen but the console window still appears. The argument maybe something like "-s". So is there any way I can do this without using the "if" condition in each class and passing an parameter through classes? Many thanks.

P/S: I've searched thru the internet and found out some articles related to this, but most of the answers were to hide the console window. I think this question should be what the others meant.

Comment: You can parse input -s in application main function, then redirect console output to file, for  example, not to screen, using Console class methods

Comment: Usually you should use Debug/Trace to control this kind of behavior.

Comment: @Artur: actually I don't want the console to output to any other file, I just want to "hide" the output, and still I need some text to appear on the console screen, not hiding all. AMisssico's answer solved this problem of mine, I just need to set the output stream to a null TextWriter and then set back to standard output stream whenever I want.

Comment: @sajoshi: not really understand your suggestion. How does Debug/Trace work in this situation?

Comment: I am not sure why would like to hide the output. My understanding that you are outputting the information so that you have some trace information available.

Comment: @sajoshi: Ok let me explain. E.g. I wrote a winform app with a button that allows user to run a console app (this is the one that I mentioned in the question). There are choices to add arguments (by checking the check boxes) to the console app, and "-s" is a choice that will hide the output text on console screen. If I hide the console window, there will be no problem. But I still want to put some texts there to inform that the jobs is running silently (but actually just not outputting the text on screen). If you hide the window or clear console screen, this will be different from my purpose.

Comment: Sorry, want to give the example code but it seems that I cannot use preformatted text and code in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Console.SetOut (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) and pass in a "null" text writer. The idea on `-s` perform a `Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter())`.

The example for the `Console.SetOut` method will help you get started.

In addition, you can easily add logging using this method.

Comment: Does this work when output is provided from third party library or process started from my code?

Answer (score 7):

The [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) method throws a `ArgumentNullException` if you pass `null` directly; same for `StreamWriter` (if you [pass a stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx) or if you [pass a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx).

What I use is passing the special [`Stream.Null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null.aspx) field to a `StreamWriter`:

```
System.Console.SetOut(new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream.Null);
```

This redirect the stream to what is essentially the null device (`/dev/null` on *NIX machines).

Answer (score 4):

Use these methods to redirect output (programmatically):

```
    Console.SetIn(...);
    Console.SetOut(...);
    Console.SetError(...);
```

Comment: I like your answer, too. But AMissico's answer is more detailed. Thanks anyway ^^.

Answer (score 3):

```
app.exe > nul
```

redirects output to nowhere. FYI: [Using command redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: +1 i am pretty sure he meant for a solution in code, but this is really cool :D

Comment: sorry but I really mean to pass in a parameter, so that I can define my own parameters. Furthermore, I still want to output some text such as a beginning like "Running in silent mode..." or so, if you redirect the output to nowhere, all of the output won't appear anymore.

Comment: Good tip! Good resource link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across [Console.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear.aspx), you could call this in a way that makes it appear no text at all was output.

As for avoiding having to separately define this in each class you should look at inheritance.  This allows you to define the functionality in one place and each 'sub' class will inherit this.

Comment: I worked on a project that belongs to a previous team, not a new one. If I have to modify all the classes, this will be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to define the items you want to log. It allows you to log regarding log level, regarding which class you want to log and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked pretty well for **me**!:

```
Console.SetOut(StreamWriter.Null);
Console.SetError(StreamWriter.Null);
```

This doesn't work:

```
Console.SetOut(null);
Console.SetError(null);
```

It results in an `ArgumentNullException`.

This doesn't work:

```
Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(null));
Console.SetError(new StreamWriter(null));
```

Because it is ambiguous between `new StreamWriter(string path)` and `new StreamWriter(Stream stream)`.

And *finally*, neither of these work:

```
Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(default(string)));
Console.SetError(new StreamWriter(default(Stream)));
```

Because they also result in an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: For whom? :) Anyway, could you add more details and explain what's behind you answer? It can help the poster to understand your answer better...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Moot point, because the accepted answer shows using new StreamWriter(), which doesn't exist.