# Catch all STDOUT/STDERR in a catch/try statement

Tags: c#

In C# I have a function that display its errors on `STDERR`. I would like to catch everything that is printed to `STDERR` inside a parent catch/try

```
bool status = true;
Console.WriteLine("Action status: ");
try {
    talkative_function();
} catch {
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    status = false;
} 
if (status) Console.WriteLine("Ok");
```

My current output is:

```
Action status:...System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1234
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at MyProject.MyClass.MyMethod()   Error
```

And the wanted output is:

```
Action status: Error
```

How to implement this?

Comment: MSDN is having issues for me at the moment, but check [Console.SetError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror.aspx). See also [How to hide output (not the window) in a console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412701/how-to-hide-output-not-the-window-in-a-console-application).

Comment: Try setting `Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);`

Comment: Does `talkative_function()` throw an exception? It sounds like it doesn't in which case unless it returns error details then this won't work. You might be able to fire an event when something is written to STDERR though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
        Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);
        bool status = true;
        Console.Write("Action status: ");
        try {
            talkative_function();
        } catch {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            status = false;
        }
        if (status) Console.WriteLine("Ok");
```

Note that I also changed `Console.WriteLine("Action status: ");` to `Console.Write("Action status: ");` so the message appears on one line as you requir

Comment: Should I restore the `Console.SetError` after it?

Comment: Yes you can if you want